# Высота блока

Tags: html, css

У меня есть блок div внутри ячейки таблицы.

Я хочу, чтобы его высота всегда была 100%

Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: а чем вам `<div style="width:100%">` не угодил?

Comment: тем, что он все равно остается width:0

И только при появлении содержания она начинает растягиваться

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы браузер смог вычислить высоту в процентах, необходимо задать высоту "почти" у каждого из родителей.

Например:

```
<div style="width:300px;height:300px">
  <table style="height:100%">
    <tr><td style="height:100%">
      <div style="height:100%;background:red">
        stretched vertically
      </div>
    </td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Однако, следует иметь в виду, что если в другой ячейке, например, будет картинка высотой больше 300px, то таблица расползется и div растягиваться до 100% не будет, точнее 100% так и останутся рассчитанными относительно родителей.